GIT quotient and orbifolds
Let $G$ be a connected complex reductive group. Suppose $G$ acts on a smooth complex affine variety $X$. Assume the stabiliser $G_x$ of every point $x\in X$ is finite. Is it true that $X/\!/G$ is an orbifold? I.e., does $X/\!/G$ have, at worst, quotient singularities?

If $X$ is singular then this is certainly not true

Sorry I meant to include the word smooth. It is corrected now.

How about Luna's slice theorem? This post.

The Luna slice theorem does indeed seem to be relevant. Although I found the answer to this post better suited for the question. If somebody can expand this into an answer, I would be grateful. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435428/intuition-for-lunas-%C3%89tale-slice-theorem
